# Array Formula to Automatically Calculate

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, max, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want an array formula to use with Google Forms data to automatically calculate running metrics on my data.

In this case, in column BF I want it to auto-calculate whenever new responses come in.

I'm trying to use this formula below but isn't working for all column, just for the first line.

`=ArrayFormula(If(isblank($BF$3:$BF);"";(INDEX($C$1:$BD$1;0;MATCH(MAX($C3:$BD3);$C3:$BD3;0)))))`

[image: My Google Sheet]

What I'm doing wrong?

My Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iD75djqdY8qtClEHpKUEvAS55bP0ARv9AnDUz9mFBuc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the formula on the second line?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with fake data

Comment: @player0 ok, now there is a copy!

Comment: @indofraiser look, now there is a copy of my sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete range **BE:BF**

paste this in **BE1**:

```
={"MAX"; ""; ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C3:BD); 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(A3:A<>""; 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A3:A)-ROW(A3)+1&")"; ))&"")); 
 "select Col2"; 0))}
```

paste this in **BF1**:

```
={"TIPO"; ""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="";;TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C3:BD=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C3:BD); 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(A3:A<>""; 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A3:A)-ROW(A3)+1&")"; ))&"")); 
 "select Col2"; 0); C1:1; ));;99^99)))))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is it possible I add two more columns beside column "TIPO" with the second and third highest value? If yes, which code can I use? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work, when I change "select Col 2 to select Col 3" returns a lot of "#VALUE! #VALUE!..."    :(

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tr2ax-gQR3Nsel91DSf28lmwBY-eWZvSXWFX8lDxM7o/edit#gid=697227740

Comment: man could you help me with this one? :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004977/arrayformula-to-automatically-calculate-one-column