# ArrayFormula to automatically calculate one column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want an array formula to use with Google Forms data to automatically calculate running metrics on my data.

In this case, in column **Q**, **AE** and **AS** I want it to auto-calculate whenever new responses come in.

I'm trying to use this formula below but isn't working for all column, just for the first line.

```
={arrayformula(if(len(AF3:AF);SUM(vlookup(AF3:AR3;$A$1100:$B$1101;2;0));))}
```

I want a sum of all words that contain "Verdadeiro" in a row.

What I'm doing wrong?

My Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVQ772IIXI-xZza0fecTTCe4S-Ku9rL1houTMnQZpbo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi if the existing answer doesn't resolve your issue, could you please include your expected output in your sample sheet? I can't fully understand your goal particularly this "sum of all words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
={"Total AG";""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="";;
 MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH(A3:AR&""; "Verdadeiro")); SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A3:AR))^0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! You are the best! Thanks!

Comment: man... sorry but could you help me with that too hehe :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531907/arrayformula-to-automatically-calculate-specifics-columns