# ArrayFormula to automatically calculate specifics columns

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, calculated-columns

I want an array formula to use with Google Forms data to automatically calculate running metrics on my data.

In this case, in column H, M, R and S I want it to auto-calculate whenever new responses come in. Columns H, M and R are ok except for column **S**.

I'm trying to use this formula below for the sum of each row in these specific columns H, M and R results in a **grand total** at the column S but isn't working.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SE(A2:A="";; MATRIZ.MULT(H2:H+M2:M+R2:R; TRANSPOR(SINAL(COL(H2:H+M2:M+R2:R))))))
```

What I'm doing wrong?

My Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6ZLnonx8BZ_KV0elW5xiuyQZPi86LOIUzdyVbBHAXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Mind that adding the arrays in TRANSPOR(SINAL(COL(H2:H+M2:M+R2:R))) results in an array of values while COL() needs a range... So either avoid COL() or use some range inside it

Comment: It looks like the `COLUMN(H2:H+M2:M+R2:R)`part produces an error, as it needs a cell range, instead of your current implementation. Do you have any reasons why you're specifically using a combination of MMULT in ARRAYFORMULA when calculating the grand total of every row of columns H,M, R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this at the beginning of your formula:

`SE(A2:A=""`

But A2:A is blank for all rows. So you are getting blanks in Column S, because that is what you instructed the formula to do.

Since you know that you will have something in R2:R of every active row, just change that segment of your formula to the following:

`SE(R2:R=""`

However, you are adding formulas directly to the form intake sheet. This is never a good idea; it can cause many problems. The professional standard is to leave form intake sheets alone, with no additional formulas, columns, conditional formatting, etc. Instead, use a separate sheet to bring over results from the form intake sheet and then process/add in that second sheet.